# tar.gz file wont open

Tags: command-line

I have been trying to install this software but had no lucks heres the command i have been  trying to run

```
eli-Inspiron-530 Downloads # tar -zxvf M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

any help would be great also
here is the download link as requested in the comments 
http://printm3d.com/files/software/linux/M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz

Comment: My guess is a corrupt download.

Comment: Post the output of `file M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz`. the output should look like `M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)` if not then probably your file is corrupted or it's not a tar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the [M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz](http://printm3d.com/files/software/linux/M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz) and got the same error when trying to extract the contents of the archive from the terminal. The Archive Manager application extracted the contents of the archive successfully however. The results of `file M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz` are `POSIX tar archive (GNU)` so it's clear that M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz is a tar archive.

You can also extract the contents of M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz from the terminal with the following commands:

```
mv M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar # rename it as a tar archive (application/x-tar)
tar -xvf M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar
```

Comment: I don't think `mv` is mandatory. You can just untar it with leaving out the `z` option. It happens sometime that tar files have `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` extensions but are not zipped.

Comment: Link to download M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz: http://printm3d.com/files/software/linux/M3D-Linux-1.5.0.70.tar.gz

Comment: @nobody Leaving out the z option without the  running the `mv` command first was the first thing I tried. Leaving out the z option worked on my computer, but only if I renamed the archive with `mv` first.

Comment: did you get the software to install?

Comment: @elliotpoppenhouse First you need to install mono-runtime and mono-xdp4 with `sudo apt install mono-runtime mono-xsp4` Now you don't need to add any third-party repositories to your software sources because the dependency packages have been installed from the default Ubuntu repos. Next follow the official installation instructions in the README-1.5.70.pdf file from http://printm3d.com: http://printm3d.com/files/software/linux/README-1.5.0.70.pdf

Comment: Mono is an open source development platform based on Microsoft's .NET framework which is used to build Linux and cross-platform applications